# Unable to create a constant value of type 'Closure type'

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

Here is my linq to entity query and I'm getting this error

"Unable to create a constant value of type 'Closure type'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context. 
"

Does any one know how to fix it or workaround.

PS. I'm using **Linq to Entity** not Linq to SQL

```
List<int> listint
List<int> listintTwo

  return (from oa in _entity.TableOne
          join cc in _entity.TableTwo on oa.TableSix.ColumnOne equals cc.TableSix.ColumnOne
          join os in _entity.TableThree on oa.TableThree.ColumnTwo equals os.ColumnTwo
          join cs in _entity.TableTwotatus on cc.TableTwotatus.ColumnThree equals cs.ColumnThree
          join app in _entity.TableFour on cc.TableFour.ColumnFour equals app.ColumnFour
          join cl in _entity.TableFive on app.TableFive.ColumnFive equals cl.ColumnFive
          where listint.Any(x =>x == cc.TableTwotatus.ColumnThree)
          && listintTwo.Any(x => x == os.ColumnTwo) && cc.TableSix.ColumnOne == ColumnOne 
          select new TableFive {ColumnFive = cl.ColumnFive, CompanyName = cl.CompanyName}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your calls to `Any(...)` to `Contains(...)`

```
where listint.Contains(cc.TableTwotatus.ColumnThree)
&& listintTwo.Contains(os.ColumnTwo) && ...
```

I'm pretty sure it's having problems with you referencing a joined entity from the lambda expressions (acting as closures).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot query entities with the complex types. So first get the result from the EF and then join with your complex type.

```
List<int> listint
List<int> listintTwo

return (from oa in _entity.TableOne
      join cc in _entity.TableTwo on oa.TableSix.ColumnOne equals cc.TableSix.ColumnOne
      join os in _entity.TableThree on oa.TableThree.ColumnTwo equals os.ColumnTwo
      join cs in _entity.TableTwotatus on cc.TableTwotatus.ColumnThree equals cs.ColumnThree
      join app in _entity.TableFour on cc.TableFour.ColumnFour equals app.ColumnFour
      join cl in _entity.TableFive on app.TableFive.ColumnFive equals cl.ColumnFive).ToList().
      where listint.Any(x =>x == cc.TableTwotatus.ColumnThree)
      && listintTwo.Any(x => x == os.ColumnTwo) && cc.TableSix.ColumnOne == ColumnOne 
      select new TableFive {ColumnFive = cl.ColumnFive, CompanyName = cl.CompanyName}).ToList();</pre>
```